# why a pointer can be assigned value?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a puzzle here:

```
int *a=*b;
a[1]=3;
a[2]=5
```

a is a pointer array and is assigned value as b. In my understanding, a[]should be a address, so why in practice we can assign value to the place the pointer (in this case a[]) to? Any explain?

Comment: `a[1]` is exactly the same as writing `*(a + 1)`. Obviously you can write `*a = 3` since `a` is `int*`, so you can also write `*(a + 1) = 3`, so you can also write `a[1] = 3`.

Comment: `a` is not a pointer array. `a` is a pointer.

Comment: what is *(a+1)? you mean *a[1]?

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I wrote. Try it, then find some pointer tutorials to freshen up your knowledge.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is C, or the C subset of Objective C/C++, since C+, Java, PHP, and the other C-like languages don't use pointers.

Use code tags and a single statement per line.

The statement

```
int *a = *b;
```

Creates a as a pointer to int. Not a pointer to pointer to int, a pointer to an int.

It then sets the current address in a to be a dereference of b, whatever b is. You did not show the declaration of b. Unless b is of type `int **`, you should be getting a compiler warning.

a is not a pointer array. a is a pointer to an int. It could point to a single int, or it could be made to point to an array of ints. The compiler can't tell the difference..

If b is of type `int **`, or pointer to pointer to int, then your statement dereferences one of those pointers and makes a point to the first sub-array inside b.

The code

```
a[1] = 3;
```

assumes that a is a pointer to an array of integers, and since the compiler can't do any range checking, it tries to index into the array and save a value to the second int in the block of memory that a points to. If a does not point to a block of memory large enough to contain at least 2 integers, this statement may crash on a modern computer using protected memory, it might also just overwrite the memory that follows.

As @EdS. points out in a comment  below, this is known in the business as

"undefined behavior"

If you're going to use a C pointer like this, the burden is on you to make sure that it really points to valid memory, and if you're going to use a pointer as if it's an array, you the burden is on you to make sure that you don't exceed the bounds of the memory pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: This is all good, but really, there should be at least a single mention of the term *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

But let's answer to your question:

Here am I going step by step through your code (though I modified it a bit for the purpose of the example), and show you what it is doing in a fake memory, so you get the idea:

```
int b[4];
```

here you allocate 4 cells of memory and make `b` a label for a memory cell containing the address of the first memory cell:

```
variable     b                      
address      0x1   0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5 
memory      [0x2] [   |   |   |   ]
```

then:

```
int* a = b;
```

here you allocate a new memory cell that can contain an address, as it is declared with a pointer type, and you assign to it the content of the `b` memory cell:

```
variable     b                       a
address      0x1   0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5   0x6
memory      [0x2] [   |   |   |   ] [0x2]
```

then:

```
a[1]=3;
a[2]=5;
```

you're setting a value to `a[1]` which translates to `*(a+1)` using pointers arithmetics, which is the content of address `0x2 + 1` i.e. content of `0x3`. Same thing with `a[2]`. The memory is now:

```
variable     b                       a
address      0x1   0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5   0x6
memory      [0x2] [   |  3|  5|   ] [0x2]
```

I hope this ASCII will make it a bit more clear how arrays are working! And you should definitely read the [Kernighan and Ritchie book](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf), as well as [this documentation](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/cdescent/) which both explain very well how the whole memory is managed, and the pointers arithmetics, and arrays.

Comment: N.B.: this is what happens to answers when answering just after reading stuff like [this](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2014/01/the-lost-ancestors-of-ascii-art/283445/)

Comment: and really, read the book and the online documentation, they should really help you!

Comment: Ok, I will. I am new to c codes. Again thanks for your answer.

Comment: well, if you like to thank me, I'd prefer `+1` instead of a `-1` :->

Comment: what is that? I did nothing on this.

Comment: ok, right, wrongly assumed about the types, based on my changed example… but it's crazy to see that it's getting -3 because of that 1% of the explanation, where I tell the OP to refer to other's comments anyway.

Comment: N.B.: edited the post and removed that part ; and if you've got other concerns, I'd be glad to hear, so I can improve my answer. When I take time to do something, I don't like to throw it out.